# Не загружается текст при парсе

Tags: html, python, парсер

Пытаюсь спарсить текст по id но выводит только id и тд без текста между ними. Вот что выводиться:"тут должен быть текст но он не выводиться" . А вот как я ищу:stat = soup.findAll(id="player_value") . Есть предположение что на сайте задержка (подгружается не сразу данные). Но допустим как через bs4 сделать задержку или убрать? python 3.8.2 (если что).

Comment: Похоже, Что Это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Comment: почему? я просто не пойму как сделать задержку

Comment: `bs4` — это библиотека для парсинга. Она никак не взаимодействует с сетью, только с тем документом, что Вы **передали**. В общем случае можете воспользоваться `Selenium`, чтобы загрузить сайт и исполнить `JavaScript`, который сформирует страницу полностью. Но иногда это излишне, всё зависит от конкретной архитектуры сайта.

Comment: То есть нельзя по другому сделать задержку в парсинге?

Comment: то есть как я понял джс подгружает информацию а я ее не могу найти тк беру хтмл код?

Comment: Да, в изначальном `HTML` нет этих данных (если Вы правильно пытались их парсить). Проверить это очень легко — зайдите на страницу и нажмите `Ctrl + U`.